# How can I reach inside nested object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I reach `isBoatOwner` so I can return it's value in a array?

My code is returning `undefined`.

```
pluck(
  [
    { name: "Tim", isBoatOwner: true },
    { name: "Matt", isBoatOwner: false },
    { name: "Elie" }
  ],
  "isBoatOwner"
);

function pluck(defObj, key) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < defObj.length; i++) {
    if (Object.keys(defObj[i]) == key) {
      arr.push(defObj[i][key]);
    } else {
      arr.push(undefined);
    }
  }
  return arr.flat();
}
```

Comment: `Object.keys(defObj[i]) == key` You are comparing an array to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are trying to compare an array to a string to see if the property exists. That is never going to match

```js
function pluck(defObj, key) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < defObj.length; i++) {
    // if (Object.keys(defObj[i]) == key) {
    if (defObj[i][key] !== undefined) {
      arr.push(defObj[i][key]);
    } else {
      arr.push(undefined);
    }
  }
  return arr.flat();
}

var result = pluck(
  [{
      name: "Tim",
      isBoatOwner: true
    },
    {
      name: "Matt",
      isBoatOwner: false
    },
    {
      name: "Elie"
    }
  ],
  "isBoatOwner"
);

console.log(result);
```

But the check does not make too much sense since you are pushing undefined into it. So it could just be

```js
function pluck(defObj, key) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < defObj.length; i++) {
    arr.push(defObj[i][key]);
  }
  return arr.flat();
}

var result = pluck(
  [{
      name: "Tim",
      isBoatOwner: true
    },
    {
      name: "Matt",
      isBoatOwner: false
    },
    {
      name: "Elie"
    }
  ],
  "isBoatOwner"
);

console.log(result);
```

Modern approach is just map

```js
function pluck(defObj, key) {
  // return defObj.map(function(item) { return item[key]; });
  return defObj.map(item => item[key]);
}

var result = pluck(
  [{
      name: "Tim",
      isBoatOwner: true
    },
    {
      name: "Matt",
      isBoatOwner: false
    },
    {
      name: "Elie"
    }
  ],
  "isBoatOwner"
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me. I was in stuck-ville with this question for half the day. I really understand it now .

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a simple `.map()`:

```js
console.log(pluck(
  [
    { name: "Tim", isBoatOwner: true },
    { name: "Matt", isBoatOwner: false },
    { name: "Elie" }
  ],
  "isBoatOwner"
));

function pluck(defObj, key) {
  return defObj.map(function (obj) {
    return obj[key];
  });
}
```

So the above function collects all the values of `isBoatOwner` from the array and sends it as an array of values.

```
[
  true,
  false,
  undefined
]
```